# Spring Boot testing with embedded H2 executes 10 times the init scripts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

Context:

- Java
- Spring Boot 2.4.1
- Testing with a H2 database
- I'm not using JPA

```
# data source configuration (The one failing, I have another 2 data-sources):
jdbc-url: "jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM './schema_1.sql'\\;RUNSCRIPT FROM './data1.sql'"
username: "sa"
password: "sa"
driver-class-name: "org.h2.Driver"
```

```
# schema_1.sql:
create schema if not exists `schema_1`;
create table if not exists job_run (
    last_run datetime,
    country varchar(2),
    UNIQUE KEY `country` (`country`)
);
```

```
# data1.sql:
INSERT INTO `job_run` (`last_run`, `country`) VALUES ('2020-12-12 00:00:00', 'UK');
```

When I run the @SpringBootTest I'm able to turn the application on but the init scripts are executed 10 times.
It's not a big deal with the create tables contained in schema_1.sql because I just added the "IF NOT EXISTS"; The problem came while I started wanting the data, that, due to table constraints (that I need) and the tests scope I cannot accept 10 times the same record.

I know it is trying to execute it 10 times because before adding the UNIQUE constraint I saw that the same record was inserted that many times.

Is that any explanation to this behavior? I'm seriously not getting it.

Anyways, it is throwing an obvious:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.COUNTRY_INDEX_D ON PUBLIC.JOB_RUN(COUNTRY) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO `job_run` (`last_run`, `country`) VALUES ('2020-12-12 00:00:00', 'IT') [23505-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.getDuplicateKeyException(BaseIndex.java:103) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.checkUnique(MVSecondaryIndex.java:221) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.add(MVSecondaryIndex.java:196) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:531) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:195) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:151) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.RunScriptCommand.execute(RunScriptCommand.java:79) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.RunScriptCommand.update(RunScriptCommand.java:58) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.executeRemaining(CommandList.java:50) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.update(CommandList.java:67) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:243) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:171) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:166) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:29) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:340) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:173) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:725) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:711) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: your init scripts might be executed every time a new db connection is created

Comment: This is not related to Spring Batch so I removed the `spring-batch` tag. It's hard to guess the root cause of this from what you shared, but I think this is due to your jdbc connection query containing: `INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM './schema_1.sql'\\;RUNSCRIPT FROM './data1.sql'"`. This is probably causing the scripts to be executed on each connection as mentioned by @eHayik. Have you tried the standard Spring Boot mechanisms of db initialization: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc ?